# "Was it fun there?" or "How did you like there?"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

I am learning English. Once a friend is speaking her travel experience in a foreign country and I wanted to ask her how the experience is, did she enjoy it. So in this case, are these two sentences valid?

> Was it fun there?
>   How did you like there?
>   How did you like X country?

Also, conversely, if my friend is travelling in my country and I'm local, I want to know if she likes my country. What should I ask? Is this sentence good?

> Is it fun here?
>   Do you like it here?

Comment: If you are learning English, you should really use our [ell.se] site.

Comment: Yes, those sentences are fine by the way.

Comment: "How did you like [X country]?" "Did you enjoy your trip?"  "Did you have a good time?" are better than "Was it fun?" The traveller may well have had some fun (amusing and entertaining times) there, but presumably you are asking about her experiences in general.

Comment: @ – marcellothearcane - "How did you like there?' is not fine.

Comment: That's right. _Like_ requires a direct object, so you have to say _like **it** here_ instead of just _like here_.

Answer (score 2):

If your friend visited a foreign country, you could say any of the following.

> A. *"Was it fun there?"* or even better *"Did you have fun there?"*
>
> B. *"How did you like **it** there?"*

Note that it is possible for a person to have fun in a foreign country and not like the country at the same time. They might have had fun meeting their relatives and friends, doing certain activities, or going to some specific places. But they might not have liked the polluted environment, the road congestion, and the high price level.

Hence, if someone says they did not like "Country X", it does not necessarily mean they did not have fun there.

> C. *"How did you like "Country X"?"*

If someone asked me that question, I would most likely start talking about the beauty of the country and the great things about the country. If you want to ask your friend about their daily debauchery, then *"Did you have fun?"* would be a better choice.

If your foreign friend is visiting your country, you could ask

> D. *"Do you like it here?"* or *"How are you liking it here so far?"* or *"How are you liking Country X so far?"* or *"What do you think of my country?"*

But this to me is very awkward

> E. *"Is it fun here?"*

Instead, you could ask

> F. *"So, are you having fun yet?"*

Comment: Thank you for writing such a thorough answer. One small question, is it ok to say "how are u finding x country"? is it same as  "How are you liking Country X so far?"?

Comment: @Joji Yes you can say that. Look at the meaning of [*find*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/find) in Cambridge that means *"experience a feeling"*.

Comment: Hi @AIQ. Thanks for reply. One last question, for this sentence `what do you think of my country`, can I ask `what do you think of it here` instead? or just `what do you think of here`?

Comment: @Joji *"What do you think of here?"* is not grammatical. *"What do you think of it here?"* is a bit strange to me but you can use it if you want to.

Comment: You might consider "What are your impressions of the country?", or even "What are your impressions of the places here that you visited?" That is called an "open-ended" question, because it leaves the person responding free to talk about whatever parts of it they would like to tell -- people, natural beauty, traffic, accommodations, food, the railway system, etc. And many things that are liable to strike one the most strongly are things that are NOT true of wherever they came from, which can lead to a discussion and comparison of the countries.

Comment: Sure. "Did you like [country X]?" could be a difficult question to answer. Maybe they like the food but the people are rude. Maybe they like the social customs but hate the politics. Etc. I periodically see polls where they ask people, "Do you think the country is on the right track or heading in the wrong direction?" And I think, How can you answer that? I can think of trends I think are positive and trends I think are negative. I can think of things that seem good right now but are getting worse and things that are bad but getting better. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Was it fun there?" Fine.

"Did you like there?" Close. You should say, "Did you like it there?" That is, you need the "it". Frankly I am not sure what grammar rule this relates to, but I know that that's what fluent speakers say.

"Did you like X country?" Fine if you replace "X country" with the name of the country. Like, "Did you like France?" Don't leave the word "country" in. That is, DON'T say, "Did you like France country?" If you need to make clear that you're talking about a country and not a city or something else, you can say, "Did you like the country of France?"

If you're really looking for more information and not just making polite conversation, you might want to be more specific. Like, "Did you like the climate there?" or "What did you think of the architecture?"